# Proving that the null space of this matrix only includes the zero vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Show that $x = 0$ is the only solution of $(I - P + Q)x = 0$, where $P$ and $Q$ are stochastic irreducible matrices that satisfy $PQ = QP = QQ =Q$.

This is my attempt. Let $v$ be a left eigenvector of $Q$ associated to $\lambda =1$. Then,
$v^T(I - P + Q)x = v^T(I - P)x + v^TQx = v^T x = 0$. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the property $QQ=Q$ we know that the matrix is idempotent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix. Idempotent matrices are always diagonalizable and the eigenvalues are either $0$ or $1$. Use these facts to decompose $x$ into a sum of eigenvectors and use the fact that $PQ = Q$ to determine the relationship between the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $Q$ and $P$.